# What happened to the HDEV ISS Experiment? Is it over?

Tags: iss, hdev

I've been checking on and off for a few weeks now and the offline logo seems to be always there. Is the program over? Is there another website that shows current views? Thanks for your time!

Comment: From the links mentioned in the answers so far, there is an embarrassing lack of technical explanation on the causes and tracking of the presumed death of the ISS HDEV experiment. After DSCOVR which doesn't emit since end of June, this is an other sad loss for Earth viewing... Would deserve more communication from NASA.

Comment: @MichaelBoccara From what I've seen, you're getting about what they know.  There is limited ability to troubleshoot something on orbit when you simply stop receiving data from a payload and it doesn't respond to commands.  Nailing down the cause would require retrieving and returning the payload for inspection on the ground.

Comment: HDEV Final Report: https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/files/HDEV-Final-Report_20200715.pdf

Answer (score 17):

As of 08/25/2019, according to the NASA [HDEV](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/) page:

> The High Definition Earth-Viewing (HDEV) experiment on the International Space Station has experienced a loss of data, and ground computers are no longer receiving communications from the payload. A team of engineers are reviewing the available health and status information from HDEV to identify what may have occurred. Additional updates will be published as they become available.

Comment: I didn't find any recorded past videos on the site. Probably someone has recordings, and it would be nice to see a sample.

Comment: @bitchaser there is a video archive here: http://columbuseye.rub.de/highlights/  I think anyway, I have no German.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Click on "archiv"; right panel expands. Filter by "alle highlights" and it shows 88 videos. I hope someone knows enough Deutschsprache to comment on some of them. They seem to be good quality; I haven't tried them full-screen though.

Comment: @bitchaser many thanks for the navigation tips!

Answer (score 5):

The link to the HDEV page that David Ratti gives does not give any updates further that what he mentions. However, the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Definition_Earth_Viewing_cameras) page for HDEV has more information (that I cannot find a source for)

> > Failure of the cameras (Update August 2019)
>
> Unfortunately, after five years we have to announce the end of the
>   HDEV experiment. Originally it should already be over in 2016 and we
>   are pleased that we could inspire you far beyond with the live videos
>   from the ISS. Of course, we will stay with you and continue to bring
>   Earth observation with other great sensors from the ISS into your
>   classroom.

Edit: The information I quoted has now been removed

Comment: I think this is an example of a bad Wiki edit: no citation, expression from first-person, not even googlable to anything other than this Wikipedia page, so might as well be original research or joke.

Comment: The bad news is now confirmed by the site. The live view screen now contains the message: "It is with regret that we must inform you that the ISS HDEV payload has reached End of Life". They plan to provide alternative content there.

Comment: This also is back in the Wikipedia article, with two references this time.  Even Yogi Berra would have to admit it's over.

Comment: The quote seems to come from the University of Bonn's website which is available here. [link](http://columbuseye.rub.de/live/) if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

I just received the notice in the ISS mobile app "We regret to inform you the ISS HDEV has reached End of Life."   It was a spectacular gift to have had it this long. My favorite way to pass the time was to watch the world go by, literally. Lol
(Edit @bitchaser has the exact wording up above -ty for sharing!)

Comment: Could you please extend your answer with some links?

Comment: A link to the text would be much appreciated. My comment was based on what the video screen showed, not copyable. Please include the text (or a significant portion of it at least) in your answer. Comments are not intended to be permanent.

Comment: HDEV Final Report: https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/files/HDEV-Final-Report_20200715.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Search for EHDC - it replaces HDEV. For some reasons many pages (including NASA's https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/) still mention HDEV but that has been out of action for quite a while now.